# Importing in MS Access when your data is in columns

Tags: database, ms-access, import

I'm doing A Level and came across this paper in which the data is given in columns and not rows, and is separated by commas. I'm inserting an image so it is easier to understand.

I'm fine with every other way of importing, but couldn't figure this out. I tried Fixed Width and Delimited, but no luck. Thanks in advance!

Here's the pictures.

[image]

Comment: Please add the data as text (format as code). -- The most practical way would be to import as csv to Excel, copy & insert **transposed**, then import to Access.

Comment: Transposing worked. Thanks a lot, @Andre451 you are a life saver.

Comment: Maybe you can pay him back by marking his post as answer, then

Comment: I didn't know how to do it, Markus. I found a tick and checked it. I hope that's the one. Sorry if Andre's effort seemed unappreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most practical way is to import the data as csv to Excel, copy & insert **transposed**, then import to Access.